# Coded UI Test for a website having lots of ajax calls

Tags: asp.net-ajax, coded-ui-tests

I tried to create a Coded UI Test for performance load test of websites that has lots of ajax calls -- the service server is ASP.NET. Once the page is loaded, automatically ajax requests are invoked.

BrowserWindow instance is used to open the website, and its WaitForControlReady method is used to see if the page is loaded or not. However, WaitForControlReady method does not check ajax calls, so the test finishes before the response arrives. My code is like below:

```cs
BrowserWindow bw = BrowserWindow.Launch();
foreach(string url in URLList.urls)
{
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    bw.NavigateToUrl(new System.Uri(url));
    bw.WaitForControlReady();
    DateTime stopTime = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan duration = stopTime - startTime;
    TestContext.WriteLine(duration.ToString() + " - " + url);
}
```

Is there any way to track ajax calls so that I can check the accurate loading time?

Comment: Coded UI is not ideal for load testing as a computer (real or virtual) can only run one test at a time. For load testing you normally want to simulate many users and so would need many computers to run the test. Visual Studio (Ultimate edition) has a web and load test facility that can simulate hundreds of users on a single computer. The web and load tests work at the HTTP level as so avoid the 'wait' problem you describe.

Comment: Thank you AdrianHHH. Already I have a load test suite which simulate 2000 users. What I do here is to time how long it take to open pages during the 2000-user load test. For that, I need to track all the request and response between Coded UI and the server.

Comment: When the Ajax calls do have completed is there anything shown on the screen to indicate completion? Could you call one of the `WaitForControl...` methods on a field that shows a message such as "Operation completed"?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the Ajax "Loading (image or text)" Element through Coded UI and use  **WaitForControlNotExist**(int Delay(ms)) for that element. Now your code waits till ajax loading..